# How to join two Aggregation results in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I have a data set looks as

```
{"BrandId":"a","SessionId":100,"Method": "POST"}
{"BrandId":"a","SessionId":200,"Method": "PUT"}
{"BrandId":"a","SessionId":200,"Method": "GET"}
{"BrandId":"b","SessionId":300,"Method": "GET"}
```

I wrote aggregation count distinct session id by brandid:

```
 db.collection.aggregate([
     {$group: {
                "_id": {
                    brand: "$BrandId",
                    session: "$SessionId"
                },
                count: {$sum: 1}
        }},
        {$group: {
                _id: "$_id.brand",
               countSession:{$sum:1}
        }}
    ])
```

The expected result of the query is :

```
{ "_id" : "a", "countSession" : 2 }
{ "_id" : "b", "countSession" : 1 }
```

Another query is to count where the Method is POST by brand:

```
 db.collection.aggregate([
        {$match: {Method:"POST"}},
        {$group: {
            _id: '$BrandId', 
            countPOST:{$sum:1}
       }}
    ])
```

The expected result:

```
{ "_id" : "a", "countPOST" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "b", "countSession" : 0 }
```

And now, I want to combine these two query and get the expected result as following:

```
{"BrandId:"a","countSession":2,"countPOST":1}
{"BrandId:"b","countSession":1,"countPOST":0}
```

I do not how to combine these two result of two aggregation, anyone can help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`$cond`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/#exp._S_cond) operator as follows.

```
db.Collection.aggregate(
    {
        '$group': {
            '_id': {'BrandId':'$BrandId','Session': '$SessionId'},
            'countPOST':{
                '$sum':{ 
                    '$cond': [{'$eq':['$Method','POST']},1,0]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        '$group': {
            '_id': '$_id.BrandId',
            'countSession': {'$sum':1},
            'countPOST': {'$sum': '$countPOST'}
        }
    }
)
```

Ouput:

```
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "a",
            "countSession" : 2,
            "countPOST" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "b",
            "countSession" : 1,
            "countPOST" : 0
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```